# Does it have any sense to trade upon user-defined chart(/s) in mobile app?

Tags: cfd

Made an app working on any platform including mobile. It can read FX (MetaTrader 4) data and enables possibility to compare multiple assets or show any user-defined func(-s) - does it have any sense ?
Could it be long term profitable to trade few similar assets with negative correlation same time based on say 15min chart of suggested setup (ex. S&P, WTI, USDJPY, etc.) ?

Current usage scenario - open charts of interest in MT4, switch to this app and get your own chart or indicator, no other "manual" work needed.

Comment: People compare charts all the time. This question is unclear, else, if all you want is a yes answer, it's really opinion, off topic. Sorry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the commercial possibilities of an app, not about personal finance.

Comment: Still hard to understand ?? It is question - is it usefull for trading my own or other's portfolio - in case it is useless, it will have no commercial value too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing multiple assets has value if the information that is portrayed is useful.  :->)

Taking this one step further, create and plot the Comparative Relative Strength indicator by dividing the price of security A by the price of B (two stocks, a stock and a sector or index, etc.).  CRS is not to be confused with Welles Wilder's RSI which is  used by many.

Make sure that your data is clean (no missing data points, be they hourly, daily, whatever).  This provides a comparison of  how the securities are performing relative to each other. When the CRS indicator is rising, security A (the numerator) is performing better than B.  When the indicator moves sideways,  both securities are performing similarly. When the indicator is decreasing,  B is   performing better.

This indicator is useful with pairs trading where you  buy the better performer and short the weaker issue, hoping to capitalize on the spread (reversion to the mean).

I have done an awful lot of correlated pairs trading and for me, the actual value of the spread difference between the price of A and B was the data that I needed and then massaged in Excel.

Comment: I think, it works this way yet - as you cannot open any amount on FX, it shows either Price * bought or sold (n * ) CFDs value or percents, where percents are comparable. Demo has 15min data inside, but this DAX is not 24/5 and has huge spreads @begin or end of sessions. There is also intersection made on input data, so only timestamps having value for all assets are taken into account.

Comment: Does the app come with a comment translator?

Comment: Do not understand ?? All it does read predefined chart history data (like EURUSD_M15, etc.) remove all timestamps where there are missing records for any of predefined pairs or CFDs, counts relative value starting @begin of data from 100% and shows Long or Short(reversed) charts plus sum of all (# * price or % value value per each line), also calculate average of the sum and shows that all in one chart.

Comment: Isn't relative strength useless ? You cannot have 2.1234 shares A and 0.987 shares B because you have such a chart, would tell closer to real life is same or similar base - example multiples of share prices at same time. Would tell A/B or B/A is just a artificial sake you cannot realize. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: 16 shares of A and 25 shares of B would achieve  almost the same ratio.  Or take it out two decimals to 212 shares of A and 99 shares of B.   The question of useless depends on what the information tells you and how you use it.

Comment: Suppose DCA as a base and also when using risk management you do not care about exact artificial ratio, but average price and indicator strength or suggested future. In case you have unlimited funds, you can play with numbers like PI or play martingale, in real world it is better to accumulate holdings if conditions are better and sold when you earn reasonable profit or running out of funds (kind of SL). Math is just a theory, when counting money, you have to be carefull ;-) Basic step is 1 hundreds are too big steps to keep account alive.

Comment: To repeat: This indicator is useful with pairs trading where you buy the better performer and short the weaker issue, hoping to capitalize on the spread (REVERSION to the mean).